# Measure Theory Book Recommendations for a Beginner

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm an undergraduate who is taking a more rigorous probability class next year, and I'm interested in learning some measure theory to prepare.  My most relevant experience is taking a semester of real analysis (in multiple variables).  Although my primary motivation is probability theory, I'd eventually also like to learn functional analysis.  I like books that provide some intuition and motivation for the results, as well as having good exercises.  For example, one book that I particularly like is Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*.  Some books that others have recommended to me are Stein-Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*, Tao's *An Introduction to Measure Theory*, and Axler's *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis*.

Do you have recommendations for books based on the above considerations?  I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: I heard that books of Evans are very good.  But I don't know if it is related with probability.
Federer's book is also a classic in Measure Theory I think but it is not for the first course.

Comment: @Maciej Ficek: Federer's book is not for a second or third course either! As for recommendations, most books mentioned thus far here seem to me to be fairly advanced and quite lengthy, and not what I'd recommend to a beginner. A relatively short and elementary text that covers general measure/integration theory (not just Lebesgue measure and integration), which is needed for probability, is [**Elements of Integration**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0471054577) by Robert G. Bartle (1966).

Comment: Federer’s book is more on geometric measure theory, not measure theory, which is introduced just for setting the notation. Suggesting it to a person that took only multivariable analysis and not even functional analysis means you haven’t even read the question. In any case, you totally missed the point.

Answer (score 3):

I leave you a list of books on measure theory:

1. Ash, R., Real Analysis and Probability, Academic Press, (1972).
2. Evans, L., Gariepy, R., Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions, CRC Press, (1992).
3. Folland, G., Real Analysis. Modern Techniques and their applications, John Wiley, (1984).
4. Halmos, P. Measure Theory, Springer.
5. Axler, S., Measure, Integration and Real Analysis, Springer (2020).

**Remarks:**
Folland's book is very good, it has good problems. It is a course in measure theory in depth. Ash's book is probability oriented, it is also somewhat dense to read but still quite good. Sheldon Axler's book to my taste is the most didactic and is very pleasant to read, it was published and the digital version is free on the Springer page, and I think it is the most recommended to start.

Edit: Axler's book also begins to see topics of functional analysis

Comment: Ash's book is hands down the best book in measure theory and probability theory out there.

Anothe really good option is Measure Theory by Cohn.

Comment: Thank you very much!   Just to clarify, do you recommend these books over Tao's and Stein-Shakarchi's?

Comment: Stein's book is good, it has many exercises and examples, the Tao book I would not recommend, it is more a review of results

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, the electronic version of my book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis is available for free at the Springer website. Or go to https://measure.axler.net/ for the most recent electronic version (still free) that corrects a few typos.